# cannot use map function with Row and Col in render part using react-bootstrap in a react.js application

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) along with [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/). I installed react-bootstrap with the following command :

```
npm install react-bootstrap
```

instead of

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

as I wanted to use CDN for stylesheet.

Now I want to show `products_all` from state to render in a Row-Column style so that each `Row` contains 4 `Cols`.  The `products_all` state is filled up with an ajax call with `axios` which I do not show here to keep the code concise.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
    import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'

    class ProductsWise extends Component {

        constructor (props) {
          super(props)
      
          this.state = {
            products_all:[],
            
          }
    
    
           render () {

              const cols = this.state.products_all.map( (item, idx) => ( 
        
               <Col key={item} lg={3}>
                    ....
               <Col>

               ));

               
            const noRows =  Math.ceil(this.state.products_all.length / 4);
        
            const rows = Array.from(Array(noRows)).map((n, i) =>(
              
              <Row>
             
                  {cols.slice(i* 4, i * 4)}

              </Row>

            ));
        
            return rows;
           }
          }

export default ProductsWise
```

But with `npm run watch` command in command prompt I get the error :
**Unterminated JSX contents** which indicates at `</Row>`.

So how to get rid of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a `/` to your second `Col` to close it, i.e. `</Col>`

Answer (score 0):

This would work now, the error was because you missed / in Col. After that you would have got {} error as well. Structured it for you :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// use destructuring to import from reactstrap
import { Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';

// { } braces where not used properly
class ProductsWise extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products_all: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    const cols = this.state.products_all.map((item, idx) => (
      <Col key={item} lg={3}>
        ....
      {/* YOU WHERE MISSING / HERE HENCE THE ERROR */}
      </Col>
    ));
    const noRows = Math.ceil(this.state.products_all.length / 4);
    const rows = Array.from(Array(noRows)).map((n, i) => (
      <Row>{cols.slice(i * 4, i * 4)}</Row>
    ));
    return rows;
  }
}

export default ProductsWise;
```